# How to use cordova plugin cordova-plugin-inline-datepicker?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, datepicker, ionic4

I’m developing an ionic 4 app and want to use cordova plugin [cordova-plugine-inline-datepicker](http://%20https://github.com/unumotors/cordova-plugin-inline-datepicker)

instead of native ionic datepicker plugin but I’m getting an error

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
```

Impostazioni.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams,Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
declare var cordova:any;

@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-impostazioni',
 templateUrl: 'impostazioni.html',
 })
 export class ImpostazioniPage {
 constructor(private platform: Platform) {

 show(){
 this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  //alert('dentro');
  let element = document.querySelector('.inline-datepicker');
  let options = {
    'mode': 'date',//cordova.plugins.DatePicker.Mode.DATE'', // default is 
  DATE_AND_TIME
    'date': new Date(),
  };
  let success = function (data) {
    // this callback is called everytime input is changed
    //document.querySelector('.date-label').innerText = new 
  Date(data.date).toLocaleDateString();
    alert('success');
  }
  let error = function (data) {
    // this callback is called everytime input is changed
    //document.querySelector('.date-label').innerText = new 
  Date(data.date).toLocaleDateString();
    alert('error: ' + data);
  }


  cordova.plugins.DatePicker.create(element, options,success, error);

    cordova.plugins.DatePicker.show(element, options,success, error);
});
}
}
}
```

impostazioni.html

```
<ion-content padding>
<div class="date-label" (click)="show()">No date selected</div>
<div class="inline-datepicker" ></div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: I installed the plugin in this way:

```
npm i cordova-plugin-inline-datepicker
```

but the right way is:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inline-datepicker
```

Now the plugin compares in plugins list and the error doesn't compare anymore.

Comment: Did you get the plugin to actually output a datepicker? I'm using Ionic 5 and I'm not getting the plugin to show the datepicker. I think the "create" is working since an ID is added to the inline-datepicker element but nothing happens on "show". Would love to know how you experienced the plugin @Iva Pesa